# Rasa Core: How to combine multiple utterances for an intent

Tags: python, chatbot, rasa-core

In my `stories.md` file, if I have something like this

```
* mood_greet
 - utter_happy
 - utter_open_question
```

Only the first utter action i.e. `utter_happy` shows up and not followed up `utter_open_question`. I have followed up all the issues and the only solution I have found is to append the second question with the first dialogue and place them in an `action` function.

Any help will be highly appreciated for a beginner like me.

Comment: Does your stories.md have any other utter_happy intents, it might just be picking up another story.

Comment: Yes, I didn't pay enough attention to the stories.md file. Better stories did lead to better result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you used an old Rasa version which had a bug. With the example you have shown, it is actually the expected behavior that both, `utter_happy` and `utter_open_question`, are executed.

## Example

Story file:

```
## Story 1
* greet
  - utter_hello
  - utter_how_can_I_help
```

Domain file:

```
intents:
  - greet

actions:
  - utter_hello
  - utter_how_can_I_help

templates:
  utter_hello:
    - text: "Hi"
  utter_how_can_I_help:
    - text: "How can I help you?"
```

If you now train Rasa Core as described [here](https://rasa.com/docs/core/policies/#training) and then run Rasa Core as described [here](https://rasa.com/docs/core/quickstart/#talking-to-your-bot) and then trigger the intent `greet` by sending a message `/greet` it will utter:

```
Hi
How can I help you?
```

Possible reasons for the behavior you are having are:
* you did not put a template for `utter_open_question` in your domain file
* a problematic [policy configuration](https://rasa.com/docs/core/policies/#default-configuration)
* you are not using Rasa NLU and sent a message like "Hello". Either use Rasa Core without NLU and trigger intents by sending message with a prefixed `/` and the intent (e.g. `/<intent_name>`) or connect Rasa Core with NLU.